# Sqlite index after primary key update

Tags: android, sql, sqlite

To optimize my queries I created some indexes, but what would happen if I update primary key. It still worth to use indexes in this case?
I was reading the main concept of indexes in sqlite [here](http://sqlite.org/queryplanner.html), but did't find a nothing about this.

Table structure:

```
rowid | col1 | col2 | col3| col4 | col5
```

Indexes:

```
CREATE INDEX Idx1 ON my_tab(col1);
CREATE INDEX Idx2 ON my_tab(col1,col4);
```

Comment: You will only need to create an index once. The database will remember the columns with index and will keep changing the index along with your table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you change table data, all indexes will be updated automatically. This might slow down the UPDATE statements a little bit, but the performance of your queries will not change.

Please note that `Idx1` is superfluous and should be dropped.

Comment: Is there a source you could point to from the official sqlite docu or so?